# Find a closed expression.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We consider the real sequence $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}$, which is defined as follows:

$$     t_n = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if n = 0 }\\ 
2 &\text{ if n = 1 }\\ 
3 &\text{ if n = 2 }\\ 
2t_{n-1} + t_{n-2} - 2t_{n-3} &\text{ if n} \geq{3}\\ 
  \end{cases}        $$

To find is a closed expression of  $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}$.

I am really stuck here, anyone could give me tip for the task please?

Comment: What is the "theory of theorems"??? (This is a linear recurrence; there is a theory of linear recurrences that allows you to solve this...)

Comment: I'm fascinated. What is “the theory of theorems”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Come to think of it, it's clear that the theory of theorems is just mathematical logic. Not quite so clear how that might apply here...

Comment: Some context would be helpful. What techniques do you know for solving these kinds of problems? Do you know about generating functions?

Comment: I was so excited about this "theory of theorems". "What branch of Logic is this that I've never heard of?" I thought. Looking at the [only three results](https://www.google.com/search?q="theory+of+theorems") on Google was very disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the theory of theorems... whatever that is. This is just a linear difference equation. Once you compute the roots of the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)=\lambda^3-2\lambda^2-\lambda+2$, you get the closed form solution.
$$
t_n = c_1\cdot 1^n  + c_2(-1)^n +c_3 2^n = c_1 + c_2 (-1)^n + c_3 2^n
$$

Now you just compute $c_1,c_2,c_3$ from the initial conditions.